# "Taking the temperature" of EL&U

Tags: discussion

A cardinal guideline across all SE sites is the dictum to "be nice" in one's comments and responses. Based on my limited time on *EL&U* it would appear that participants to this site are in compliance with that policy but appearances can be deceiving.

One way to "take the temperature" of *EL&U* as suggested in the query title would be to release information wrt to "negative behaviors." Obviously the question then becomes how best to define and measure "negative behaviors." The next question concerns the time frame for any reporting, e.g., past month? past year? since site inception?

If I were to choose a single metric for "taking the temperature" of the site it would be to summarize the number of comments that have been "flagged" for not being nice and break that down by reputation segment including collapsing some of the bigger segments down to 10,000+ to maintain privacy:

[image]

This question is probably best answered by the site moderators but the opinions of other participants are, of course, welcome.

Comment: Are you trying to address any specific current issue? What would be the ideal outcome from this post in your opinion?

Comment: @DanBron  No agenda here just analytic curiosity.

Comment: Ok. I’m not sure a meta post whose answerers will necessarily have to dig into dirty laundry and find unpleasant comments is adequately repaid by satisfying our analytic curiosity.

Comment: You might be better off writing a script to collate that data.

Comment: My opinion is that the  site is unable to effectively deal with “negative behavior”, probably because different users have different perceptions of what is considered  rude, offensive or simply unfriendly langague and/or behavior, and it unltimatly comes downs to what measures  mods decide to adopt in any specific case.

Comment: @lawrence  Apologies for not making this clearer in the query but a script would be the way to go, a skill that moderators presumably possess. Moreover, there is zero interest in having anyone dig into "dirty laundry" much less air old grievances. This is a much drier abstract question than that.

Comment: @DJohnson Is your question asking for 'niceness' metrics to be defined?

Comment: @user3850720 - Apparently SE is working on turning things around and is looking for feedback and input.  See https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/ with link to questionnaire at the end. I think the best way to improve is by listening very carefully to those who've had uncomfortable experiences, so I hope you'll respond to the questionnaire, and I hope your experience will be taken into account.

Comment: @aparente001 The [questionnaire link is here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdCQNtu4KHesQz-2AzRSl8z6d4_cLgPj4B7cjNpPePc-04seA/formResponse). Side note: questionnaires that are self selected will have unknown biases, like those who care to read to the end, angry people in either direction, etc. But the more who fill it out the better.

Comment: Great idea to use actual data. Other things that have been done in the past is closing ratios, # of people who delete their account or don't come back after a while. Also, these quantitative data should be compared among SE sites, along with some other measure of 'temperature'.

Comment: @Mitch - Wait, what?  Are you saying that the raw questionnaire submissions are publicly available??

Comment: @aparente001 What????!?! No, I just gave a link for people to fill out the form. My second comment was that more could be done with the SEDE site, just being judicious about the measures used.

Comment: @Mitch - That's a lot of punctuation.  Easy does it. // I think I understand now.  When you spoke of self-selection, I now think you were talking about the respondents self selecting.  Did I get that right? // Hopefully non-angry people will fill it out too.  I wasn't angry when I filled it out -- although I did share some proposals, based on some awareness of some of the problems described in the blog post.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309763/287826.

Comment: Very helpful thread of comments. Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only database tool available is SEDE, and a [quick look at the schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678) shows that comment flags do not feature.

They are, of course, in the main database used in by the Stack Exchange engine; the "reporting database" made available via SEDE does not include this data. I believe that the `PostsWithDeleted` table is available to moderators (and may well not include 10k+ users), but that's the only nod to what we might wish to search for.

The only flags which are included are post flags raised by users who cannot vote (and which are thus a surrogate for close/reopen votes):

> PendingFlags.FlagTypeId ⋈ FlagTypes.Id
>    :   
>    :  
>    :

Quite apart from this rather fundamental problem in providing the data, I would question the premise in focusing on "Rude/Abusive" flags. They may simply be raised by someone who is thin-skinned, or (as has happened) as a vendetta against a particular user. *Accepted* flags might be a reasonable metric, perhaps.

Comment: Helpful, insightful, thoughtful and useful response.  Thank you! I agree with your point about the inherently imperfect nature of the single metric proposed wrt *negative* behaviors.  Obviously a full suite of metrics wrt *positive* as well as *negative* would be much more informative. I was proposing something simpler and more easily implemented...or so I thought.